# How to prevent full refresh using onChange event SSJS

Tags: xpages

(You may be able to figure out an answer by ONLY reading the last question by itself, but I included everything for reference if necessary)

The onChange of one field is causing displayErrors to show validation results prior to when I need it to do that.

On an xpage, I have these two comboboxes:
1.) locationType
2.) locationEtc

Choices for locationEtc are dependent on what was selected in locationType field.

In the locationEtc field, the choices are using one computed value with this code:

```
try
{
var locType = getComponent("locationType").getValue();

var key = '';

switch(locType) {
case 'Commuity Service Center':
    key = 'loc_cso';
    break;
case 'RYDC':
    key = 'loc_rydc';
    break;
case 'YDC':
    key = 'loc_ydc';
    break;
case 'HQ':
    key = 'loc_hq';
    break;
default:
    key = 'facilities';
}
    var luChoices = @DbLookup('','keywords', key, 'choices');   
    luChoices.unshift("Select one|''");
    return luChoices;
}
catch(e)
{
print("Error:::::"+e);
    }
```

The choices were NOT changing for locationEtc whenever I pick a locationType, but then they do when I add code to clear the location field whenever locationType changes, using a simple action for onChange event of locationType field:

[image]

This is great, but when it all refreshes, my displayErrors control appears (yellow background area) showing required field validation results, and a lot of the fields are not filled in yet by design.

How can I make the displayErrors to show ONLY when tying to submit?

Thanks everyone who can help.

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set disableValidators="true" on the simple action that you created

Comment: thanks Chris...wow that was easy.   So many settings makes for great flexibility, just gotta learn what they all are!